# Getting plot errors when creating custom axes

Tags: r, plot

I have an issue with the creation of custom axes in the base plotting system in R, I have the following data frame for which I want to plot a trend to show the changes for each year:

```
year  <- c(2000, 2002, 2005, 2009)
values  <- c(7332967, 5332780, 5135760, 3464206) 
x  <- data.frame(year, values)

##     year values
## 1    2000    733296
## 2    2002    533278
## 3    2005    513576
## 4    2009    346420
```

My first attempt is:

```
plot(x$year, x$value,
     xlab = "Year",
     ylab = "Value",
     type = "b")
```

However, that gives me a skewed x and y axis for the four values I have in the data frame. I would like for the x axis to only contain the four values under the "year" column and y axis to only contain the four values under the "values" column.

For this purpose I tried to create custom x and y axis but that resulted in errors:

```
plot(x$year, x$value,
     type = "b",
     xaxt = "n",
     yaxt = "n",
     xlab = "Year",
     ylab = "Values",
     axis(1, at = 1:nrow(x), labels = x$year),
     axis(2, at = 1:nrow(x), labels = x$value))

"Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value"
```

and:

```
plot(x$year, x$value,
     type = "b",
     xaxt = "n",
     yaxt = "n",
     xlab = "Year",
     ylab = "Values",
     axis(1, at = 1:nrow(x), labels = x$year),
     axis(2, at = 1:nrow(x), labels = x$value),
     xlim = c(min(data_plot$year), max(data_plot$year)),
     ylim = c(min(data_plot$Emissions), max(data_plot$Emissions)))

"Error in strsplit(log, NULL) : non-character argument"
```

I am quite new to R and tried searching for solutions on various sites, however, nothing seems to solve the issue so any help provided would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axis` is a separate function, not an argument to `plot`, so try the following:

```
# First make some extra space on the left for the long numeric axis labels
par(mar=c(5, 6, 1, 1))
# Now plot the points, but suppress the axes
plot(x$year, x$values, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', xlab='Year', ylab='', type='b')
# Add the axes
axis(1, at=x$year, labels=x$year, cex.axis=0.8)
axis(2, at=x$values, labels=x$values, las=1, cex.axis=0.8)
# Add the y label a bit further away from the axis
title(ylab='Value', line=4)
```

[image]